# I have create the Webserver in windows server 2008 for .net application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, webserver, windows-server-2008

I have created the Webserver in windows server 2008 for .net application. Now I want run my website. When I place my website in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and access through my ip address, it gives error, but this method is working fine for simple html page.

```
<compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5 />
```

How can I run successfully my asp.net webapplication on my own server ?

Comment: You aren't very clear. What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

Copy files to wwwroot folder is not enough for asp.net. You have to have iis configured to host asp.net, mark your app in iis as application, set application pool etc.

To set/check your iis configuration follow steps from this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763178(v=vs.100).aspx

To deploy your application correctly in iis follow this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0#DeployonIIS7